# jQuery horizontal scroll linking

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm currently coding a horizontal scroll website, and I'm a beginner at jQuery.

I am using this plugin:

http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

The following code is for my button that goes right, or next, through the array of divs i've set up under the class ".container". they are all sibling divs, and are right next to each other in the flow.

I found this code after some hard searching and found it on another post in stackoverflow, and it works perfectly fine to go next through my divs, one at a time.

The only problem I have is replicating a similar code to go backwards through my array. to div's i've already visited from pressing next. I want a previous button!

```
$('#arrowRight').click(function() {
    scrollLeft = $(window).scrollLeft(); 
    $(".container").each(function(i, con) {
        conLeft = $(con).offset().left;
        if (scrollLeft < conLeft) {
            $.scrollTo(con, 800);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Would anybody be able to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hacky way, reverse the array and do the opposite comparison, eg:

```
$('#arrowLeft').click(function() {
    scrollLeft = $(window).scrollLeft(); 
    $(".container").reverse().each(function(i, con) {
        conLeft = $(con).offset().left;
        if (scrollLeft > conLeft) {
            $.scrollTo(con, 800);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Might be better off storing which div is currently in view, then navigating to position [+-] 1 depending on the direction you want to go.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, unfortunately this doesn't work for me, but thank you for your input. :)